# IFormatProvider for double to engineering notation

Tags: c#, formatting

A `c#` format provider that formats a double into a string using engineering notation rules.
If the value is outside of the defined notation symbols it will default to using scientific notation.

I wrote this code to better handle a mess of case statements that previously handled the engineering notation formatting for an legacy project. The project preforms electrical measurements on a product under test, measurements like voltage, current, and resistance. These measurements are much easier for the test technicians to understand if presented in engineering notation.

```cs
class EngNotationFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<double, string> notationSymbols = new Dictionary<double, string>
    {
        {double.NegativeInfinity, ""},
        {-24, "y"},
        {-21, "z"},
        {-18, "a"},
        {-15, "f"},
        {-12, "p"},
        {-9, "n"},
        {-6, "μ"},
        {-3, "m"},
        {0, ""},
        {3, "k"},
        {6, "M"},
        {9, "G"},
        {12, "T"},
        {15, "P"},
        {18, "E"},
        {21, "Z"},
        {24, "Y"},
    };
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        double value = Convert.ToDouble(arg);

        double exponent = Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value));
        double engExponent = Math.Floor(exponent / 3) * 3;

        string symbol = notationSymbols.ContainsKey(engExponent) ? notationSymbols[engExponent] : "e" + engExponent;

        return (value * Math.Pow(10, -(int)engExponent)).ToString("0.########") + symbol;
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new EngNotationFormatter(), "{0}Ω", 0.01234)); //result: 12.34mΩ
```

---

original case statement that was placed through out code, dat here is the double to be formatted, and precision is the number of digits to display (this value is always the same)

```vb
Function formatData(ByVal dat As Single, ByVal precision As String) As String
    Select Case System.Math.Abs(dat)
        Case 0
            formatData = "0"
        Case Is < 0.000000000001
            formatData = Format(dat * 1.0E+15, precision & "f")
        Case Is < 0.000000001
            formatData = Format(dat * 1000000000000.0#, precision & "p")
        Case Is < 0.000001
            formatData = Format(dat * 1000000000.0#, precision & "n")
        Case Is < 0.001
            formatData = Format(dat * 1000000.0#, precision & "u")
        Case Is < 0.99
            formatData = Format(dat * 1000.0#, precision & "m")
            'Case Is < 1101#
        Case Is < 1000.0#
            formatData = Format(dat, precision & "")
        Case Is < 1000000.0#
            formatData = Format(dat / 1000.0#, precision & "k")
        Case Is < 1000000000.0#
            formatData = Format(dat / 1000000.0#, precision & "M")
        Case Is < 1000000000000.0#
            formatData = Format(dat / 1000000000.0#, precision & "G")
        Case Else
            formatData = ""
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: could you please provide the old code, to compare and get a better understanding on how the actual code works, and what type of environment you're dealing with. ?

Comment: @iSR5 added requested code.

Comment: the original code uses `float` while yours uses `double` is there any reason of changing the type ? because both have different precisions.

Comment: @iSR5 we were pushing the limits of what could accurately be stored in a float, as our products have been improving we will require the higher digit precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you chose to use `IFormatProvider`, and why you manually add notation using `string.Format`.

Nevertheless, `notationSymbols` will be better if you use `switch` instead, to avoid unnecessary memory allocation. if you're planning on expanding it or you don't see that a `switch` would be a good fit for your use-case, then keep it but also cache it for a reuse.

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(arg);
```

if `arg` is not valid integer (such as null) this would throw an exception.So, instead you can do this :

```
if(arg is double value) 
{
    // code
}
```

or this :

```
if(double.TryParse(arg?.ToString(), out var value))
{
    // code 
}
```

the last note when converting from lower precision to a higher one, you need to ensure the value consistency between them, which is a very common issue. So, having a plan to ensure compatibility between old precision and the new one would safe you the hassle.

Lastly, instead of implementing `IFormatProvider`, you can implement an an abstract class for notation, then use extension methods to format the numbers.

Example :

```
public abstract class EngineeringNotation
{
    private readonly char _notationSymbol;
    
    protected EngineeringNotation(char notationSymbol) {
        _notationSymbol = notationSymbol;
    }
    
    public string Format(double number)
    {
        double exponent = Math.Log10(Math.Abs(number));

        double engExponent = Math.Floor(exponent / 3) * 3);

        double result = number * Math.Pow(10, -(int)engExponent);
        
        string symbol = GetSymbol(engExponent);

        return $"{result:0.########}{symbol}{_notationSymbol}";
    }
    
    private static string GetSymbol(double exponent)
    {
        switch (exponent)
        {
            case double.NegativeInfinity:
            case 0:
                return string.Empty;
            case -24:
                return "y";
            case -21:
                return "z";
            case -18:
                return "a";
            case -15:
                return "f";
            case -12:
                return "p";
            case -9:
                return "n";
            case -6:
                return "μ";
            case -3:
                return "m";
            case 3:
                return "k";
            case 6:
                return "M";
            case 9:
                return "G";
            case 12:
                return "T";
            case 15:
                return "P";
            case 18:
                return "E";
            case 21:
                return "Z";
            case 24:
                return "Y";
            default:
                return $"e{exponent}";
        }
    }   
}

public class VoltNotation : EngineeringNotation
{
    public VoltNotation() : base('V') { }
}

public class OhmNotation : EngineeringNotation
{
    public OhmNotation() : base('Ω') { }
}

public static class NotationExtensions
{
    public static string FormatNotation(this double value, EngineeringNotation notation)
    {
        return notation.Format(value);
    }
    
    public static string FormatAsVoltNotation(this double value)
    {
        return FormatNotation(value, new VoltNotation());
    }
    
    public static string FormatAsOhmNotation(this double value)
    {
        return FormatNotation(value, new OhmNotation());
    }   
}
```

now you can do this :

```
double number   = 0.01234;
string formated = number.FormatAsOhmNotation();
```

Comment: I really like this, looking at it I realize how much the use of the previous code influenced my design, giving me tunnel vision. This seem like it addresses a feeling i have about the reparative nature of the `new EngNotationFormatter()`. thank you for taking the time

Comment: Changed `value` to `number` in `Format()`